# Using OmniDriver to deploy Java code remotely via NetBeans to a Raspberry Pi (Error with loading native USB drivers)

Tags: usb, java, raspberry-pi, netbeans

I'm writing software via NetBeans to interface with a Ocean View spectrometer and I'm running into an issue with deploying my jar file to a Raspberry Pi 3 without running into a n RunTimeException. I correctly followed the steps to deploy remote java jar files on the NetBeans IDE, but can't get past this error "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load any native library for USB.  Tried base filenames: NatUSB_32, NatUSB_64"

[Screenshot of the error in console here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8tBT.png)

My code runs successfully when compiled on the IDE, but not on the Raspberry Pi. I'm using JDK 8, and have the class path set to include OmniDriver.jar. Any help on troubleshooting this issue would be appreciated!